# Submit duplicate forms data and save in database in laravel using AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel, database, duplicates, form-submit

i am making a copy of this form i can save the data through ajax but when i add same form using anchor tag at that time i want both forms data , how can i do that using ajax?
This is my form

```
<form action="" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="addCustomField">
               
                              <input
                                  type="text"
                                  class="form-control"
                                  required
                                  id="customInputName"
                                  name="customInputName"
                                  placeholder="Pool Party"
                                  aria-label="Pool Party"
                      <div class="col-md-10">
                          <div class="form-check mb-2">
                              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="required" id="required" name="validation[]" checked />
                              <label class="form-check-label" for="required">Required</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check mb-2">
                              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="alpha" id="alpha" name="validation[]" />
                              <label class="form-check-label" for="alpha">Alphabets Only</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check mb-2">
                              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="/^[a-zA-Z\s]+$/" id="alphaSpace" name="validation[]" />
                              <label class="form-check-label" for="alphaSpace">Alphabets with Space</label>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-check mb-2">
                              <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="number" id="number" name="validation[]" />
                              <label class="form-check-label" for="number">Number Only</label>
                          </div>
              </form>
```

using javascript i am making a copy of form

```
 function duplicateForm() {
            var elmnt = document.getElementById("addCustomField");
            var cln = elmnt.cloneNode(true);
            document.getElementById("customField").appendChild(cln);
        }
```

I want to know how can i save each form data and how can i pass through ajax , first single form data i am passing like this

```
function insertData(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: {
      'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'
      }
      });
      var formData = new FormData();
      
      formData.append('customInputName',$('#customInputName').val());
      formData.append('inputType',$('#inputType').val());
      var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
      var checkedValues = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < checkboxes.length; i++) {
          checkedValues.push(checkboxes[i].value);
      }
      formData.append('checkedValues', JSON.stringify(checkedValues));
          $.ajax({
                  type: 'POST',
                  dataType: 'json',
                  url: '{{ url('/inputForm') }}',
                  data: 
                    formData,
                      // checkedValues: checkedValues
                  contentType: false,
                  processData: false, 
                  success: function(response) {
                      console.log(response);
                      var successDiv = document.getElementById('successMessage');
                      successDiv.innerHTML = response.message;
                      successDiv.classList.add('alert', 'alert-success');
                  } 
              });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Instedof cloning entire form you can clone only inside div contents

```
<form>
 <div id="clone">
   #your existing code 
  </div>
  <div class="newclone">
  </div>
</form>
```

Javascript Code

```
   function appendform() {          
        var newthing = $('#clone').clone();           
        $('.newclone').append(newthing);
    }
```

Finally Now as usual your existing submit code works well like Formdata()
So now the new append filds are coming inside the form only. **for multiple values you should verify the names are should array format like customInputName[]**